# Mysql Values not Working

Tags: mysql, database

I have a rank to determine the user level, (e.g. rank 1 = registered, rank3  = admin), and everything works fine in my script below.

```
<?php
session_start();
require('../../config.php');
$qry=("SELECT `rank`, `uname` FROM users");
$result=mysql_query($qry);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$rank = $row['rank'];
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$logged = $_SESSION['loggedin'];
  if ($logged == true) {
   if ($rank >= 3) {
    echo "Succesful, $user.<br />
      <form method='POST' action='delete.php'>
      <select><option>Please select</option>";
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $users = $row['uname'];
            $lol = ucwords($users);
           }
       echo "<option>$lol</option>";
       echo "</select>
    </form>";
   } else {
  echo "Your not an admin.";
  }
 } else {
echo "Please login.";
}

?>
```

But, once I add a new user to the database, (2 rows in database), it says "Your not an admin".

Please help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't add the where condition to specify which user? Like use the userid?

```
$qry=("SELECT `rank`, `uname` FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
```

Comment: How does that help with the rank problem? :s

Comment: @RyanRegards Why not? if you can't specify which record to use, how could you use the `rank` data? Try add `var_dump($row)` to do some debug work.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean.  Sorry for the misunderstanding, thanks for the help.

Comment: Please help, now it is only displaying a blank space in the form "Select"